# Join 2 tables based on a single table

Tags: sql, mysql

I can't seem to get the join / query that I need!

Lets say I have 3 tables (trimmed for this post...)

```
user_courses
(int) user_id
(int) course_id

users
(int) user_id
(txt) name
(txt) access

courses
(int) course_id
(txt) course_desc
```

What I am trying to do is select select all users with a certain access type that are taking a specific course (course_id)

something like...

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_courses uc
JOIN users u
ON uc.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN courses c
ON uc.course_id = c.course_id
WHERE u.access = "foobar"
```

... but working like I want it to :)
I can get close, but will have extra users that don't have the correct access type.

Comment: what's the problem? If some users don't have correct access type, than make changes in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inner join`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_courses uc
    INNER JOIN users u
     ON uc.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN courses c
     ON uc.course_id = c.course_id
  WHERE u.access = "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

```
select * from users u 
where u.access='foobar' 
    and exists (select 1 from user_courses uc where uc.user_id=u.user_id)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
WHERE ISNULL(u.access, '') = 'foobar'
```

Not sure if your 'access' field can be null?